# Instance method 'flatMap' requires that 'String' conform to 'ObservableConvertibleType'

Tags: ios, build, rx-swift, flatmap

I am getting below build error for `RxSwift`,

```
func testFlatMap() {

    let bag = DisposeBag()
    let subject = PublishSubject<String>.init()

    subject.flatMap({ (value) -> String in
            PublishSubject.just(value)
        }).subscribe(

        onNext: { value in
            print(value)
        }

    ).disposed(by: bag)

    subject.on(.next("Test"))
}
```

> Instance method 'flatMap' requires that 'String' conform to 'ObservableConvertibleType'

**What am I missing?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
subject.flatMap({ (value) -> String in
    PublishSubject.just(value)
})
```

In the first line you are telling the compiler that the closure returns a `String` but `flatMap` requires the closure to return an Observable type.

Also, FYI: `a.flatMap { .just($0) }` is effectively a no-op. 
In other words: `a` ≣ `a.flatMap { .just($0) }`